# Reproducible builds with jlink

Tags: java, jlink, binary-reproducibility

A reduced JDK (created with `jlink`) is part of our application. The required modules for the JDK image is rarely changed. Unfortunately generating a new JDK image (with the exact same `jlink` parameters) results different output, so
clients have to download the same file again and again during the differential upgrade, unnecessarily.

Here is a PoC:

```
$ mkdir jdk-15a jdk-15b
$ tar xzf openjdk-15_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz --directory jdk-15a/
$ tar xzf openjdk-15_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz --directory jdk-15b/
$ jdk-15a/jdk-15/bin/jlink --compress=1 --module-path jdk-15a/jdk-15/jmods --add-modules java.base,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.charsets --output output01
$ jdk-15b/jdk-15/bin/jlink --compress=1 --module-path jdk-15b/jdk-15/jmods --add-modules java.base,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.charsets --output output02
$ md5sum output*/lib/modules
9ae5ae63df59593a0892c5ed411d7e59  output01/lib/modules
24b4af31553670799ab286ad1186329e  output02/lib/modules
```

(I'm using the `jdk-15a` and `jdk-15b` directories similar to JDK instances on multiple build servers.)

Is there any way to get [byte-to-byte identical output (reproducible build)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducible_builds) from `jlink` in this case?

Used JDK version:

```
$ cat jdk-15a/jdk-15/release 
IMPLEMENTOR="Oracle Corporation"
JAVA_VERSION="15"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2020-09-15"
...
OS_ARCH="x86_64"
OS_NAME="Linux"
SOURCE=".:hg:e3f940bd3c8f"
```

Comment: There is [JDK-8241602](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241602) which claims to be fixed in jdk-15 build 22. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Marcono1234: Thanks for the link! It's Build 36 (2020/8/11). Should I report this as a regression?

Comment: Yes, I guess it would be good if you did that. I am also slightly confused by their fix for JDK-8241602 since it appears to not really solve the underlying issue (a collection not being ordered?).

Comment: Ok, I've reported on bugreport.java.com.

Comment: Great, could you please update this question then once a public bug report has been created.

Comment: @Marcono1234: I've added an answer with the link.

Answer (score 1):

It's a JDK bug, reported at [JDK-8252730](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8252730).